# jQuery - get select with exactly 2 options

Tags: jquery, select

I need to find all select's with exactly 2 options. The code I'm using is:

```
$('select.ct option:nth-child(2)')
```

but it seems to get everything with more than 2 options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var selects = $('select').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('option').length === 2
});
```

or:

```
var selects = $('select').filter(function() {
    return $('option', this).length === 2;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This will also work:

```
$('select:has(option:first-child + option:last-child)');
```

Basically it looks for a `select` element that contains an `option` element that is the first child and is adjacent to an `option` that is the last child.

Comment: nice, I didn't think of that.